# Load rails fixtures only into memory without hitting DB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, minitest, fixtures

I'm in the process of building the testing suite of a large, legacy application. I have a significant number of integration tests, but no unit tests (**none**). I'm trying to fix that.

The catch is, the architecture of this application is that rails/ActiveRecord only handles my web-facing pieces, validation, persistence, but then the guts of the thing are performed in POROs. These POROs roughly correspond to ActiveRecords, but there is some manipulation involved in the transformation.

Since the POROs have the business logic, I want to start by unit testing them. I initially thought to use rails fixtures, but from all I can tell, rails just loads the YAML and slams it into your testing DB, that's not what I want. In fact, the rails documentation explicitly says

> Fixtures are Active Record Objects

So then I thought to use what's built into Minitest, but that didn't fit either, since it provides stubs and mocks that my object-under-test is supposed to communicate with, instead of a way to persist my object into a test file.

So now I'm at a loss- **How do I save off test objects, so that I can load them back into memory without going through a database?**

Edit: If this is a better place for factories, that's fine too, but I already have fixtures, so I'm trying to stay in that world yet.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding your use of terminology.  In general, I assume that a PORO in Rails refers to a class whose instances are not persisted to the DB.  Do you mean something else?  And if not, why would you assume non-AR subclasses to have fixtures when they're not persisted?  Could you include code snippets to clarify?

Comment: Say I have a service object that I want to test. That service gets handed a domain object or five and performs business logic. If I want to write tests about the service, I need standard domain objects, but I don't want to write out each object explicitly, so I'm hoping to leverage existing Rails constructs to do the heavy lifting.

Comment: You could read and write YAML, and it should be easy enough to create new AR instances (not persisted to the DB unless your service objects are doing that for you) as needed.  You could also do the same with JSON, XML, or any other format that you might want to use for object serialization, but it sounds like you're creating a second data store for testing.  The difference is, this one will be slower and buggier than the database you're already building on.

But you're right about factories: if you're determined to test like this, they might be a better fit for you.

Comment: do you have a better suggestion for testing my dependency-injected services? Perhaps mocks and stubs _are_ the right choice but my objects are complex enough that I have trouble imagining I'll win anything that way over factories.